# How to remove html filter on woocommerce input price suffix?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to use the wp_filter_kses() function to remove the removal of html syntax in woocommerce price suffix input?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of hook below price html could be changed as per your expectation.

**Here is the code:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_html', 'price_custom_class', 10, 2 );

function price_custom_class( $price, $product ){ 
// your code goes here
return $price;
}
```